# yii2 disable validation on hidden fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii2

I have created a dev that is changed according to the selected radio button.
the dev has input fields:

```
<div id='div-cash' class="toHide" hidden="true"> 
        <div class="row" >

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php echo $form->field($cash[0], 'form_get',[   
                    'template' => '{label}<div class="input-group">{input}
                    <span class="input-group-addon">pt</span></div>{error}{hint}',
                    'options' => ['class' => 'form-inline toHide cashtoHide', 'style' => 'margin-top:2rem'],
                    'labelOptions' => ['style' => 'margin-right:2rem'],
                        ])->textInput();?>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

when I submit the form the inputs of the other options are validated and I want to disable it

Comment: Add your model code for more reference in question.

Comment: you might have to look into [Yii2 scenarios](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios)

Comment: Add code of model and action if exist

Comment: the validation is done before the action is posted. the controller action is not even called. it is a client side vaidation

Answer (score 0):

I used [Conditional Validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation) to solve this problem

```
'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
            return $('input[type=radio]:checked').val() == 'cash';
        }"
```